# React and Node in Websites

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, express, chatbot

I'm at this point developing a chatbot with node.js and react.

[Bot here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2xErY.png) The fact is that node.js is used as a backend to get connections to Dialogflow (NLP brain) and React is used as frontend, like the box, autoscrolling and autofocus to the last text, something like that.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zlmdy.png)

The fact is, I want to deploy in my own webpage but I can't do it. I was trying getting at least react but, the server isn't recognizing components.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/78zO0.png)

I was searching how to deploy react application on a hosted webpage, and the same with Node.js

All the information that I've found is about deploying in localhost...

Someone knows what I can do or where I should read about?
Hope you a good day guys. :)

Comment: Are your `.js` files there? It's likely it's looking for a file that doesn't exist.

Comment: Nathan, actually I've build to production the react application. I got some error inside the building code but at least I have the frontend, the fact is that I want to build to production the node environment. I was reading about tls problems with SSL certificates. In addition, I submitted the entire application to Heroku, and with some postman help, I see that I'm getting the data correctly. At this point, I'm looking to connect the bot build in react with the Heroku server app which contains the backend provided with node and the connections to Dialogflow.